# Using NotificationMole in GWT

Tags: gwt, toast

I was looking for component similar to Android's Toast notification for GWT (I Googled long enough and I know that there is a Ext-GWT which has something similar, but I want to avoid external libraries). It appears that NotificationMole is the component that I am looking for, and that this component is available in the GWT 2.1. However, when I try to show it in my app, it never appears. Has anyone used this component? Here is an example how I use it:

```
NotificationMole nm = new NotificationMole();
nm.setAnimationDuration(2000);
nm.setTitle("Title");
nm.setHeight("100px");
nm.setWidth("200px");
nm.setMessage("Test message to be shown in mole");
nm.show();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The NotificationMole has to be attached to the DOM before it can be shown:

```
HasWidgets panel; // This can be any panel that accepts children.
NotificationMole nm = new NotificatioMole();
panel.add(nm);
// Setup the NotificationMole...
nm.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void tellUser(String what) 
{
    PopupPanel pop = new PopupPanel(true);
    pop.setWidget(new Label(what));


    final PopupPanel p = pop;

    RootPanel.get().add(pop);

    pop.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {
          public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
            int left = (Window.getClientWidth() - offsetWidth) / 2;
            int top = (Window.getClientHeight() - offsetHeight) / 2;
            p.setPopupPosition(left, top);
          }
        });

    new Timer() {
      @Override
      public void run() 
      {
        System.out.println("timer repeated");
        RootPanel.get().remove(p);
        this.cancel();
      }
    }.scheduleRepeating(2000);
}
```

Comment: Why scheduleRepeating. to debug?

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak sorry I don't remember this technology or context